# C# - Fill a combobox in a datagridview using SQL Source

Tags: c#

I've seen some other articles on this, but perhaps I am doing something wrong. I'm using Visual Studio, C#, and this datagridview is using columns that are pre-defined in Visual Studio (not coded, used the GUI). That may even be part of the problem, as when I try to load the DGV, I get extra columns. Below is my code, and when populating the DGV, I just get extra columns that don't have the drop down option. How can I populate multiple rows into this DGV with drop down entries in cells that are specifically drop downs? I am trying to prevent doing a massive nested for loop in order to do these one by one if possible, as I anticipate up to 20K lines in this DGV (which I may reduce through other means, I just haven't gotten there yet).

```
private void ReadSQL(string query, DataGridView grid){
        try{
            string connectionString = "Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DATABASENAME;Persist Security Info=True;";
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
            SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            dataAdapter.Fill(table);

            bindingSource1.DataSource = table;
            //I expect something needs to happen here, not the line above.

            grid.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
            grid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            grid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DimGray;
            grid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
            grid.GridColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
            for(int i = 0 ;  i < grid.Columns.Count; i++){
                grid.Columns[i].Width = (grid.Size.Width / grid.Columns.Count) - 1;
            }
        }catch(SqlException ex){
            MessageBox.Show("SQL ERROR: " + ex.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like I am accomplishing this in a for loop, which might be efficient. I'll post this when the solution is ready, and I am always game for other ideas of approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is crude as hell, but it works. I am game for suggestions on how to write this better, i.e. the hard coding of those cases. Uncle Bob would be so mad!

```
for(int i = 0 ;  i < table.Rows.Count; i++){
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[3].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[4].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[5].ToString();}catch{}
    string selection1 = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[6].ToString();
    switch(selection1){
        case ""            : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];}catch{}; break;
        case "Found"       : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[1];}catch{}; break;
        case "Not Found"   : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[2];}catch{}; break;
        case "In Progress" : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[3];}catch{}; break;
    }
    string selection2 = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[7].ToString();
    switch(selection2){
        case ""    : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[0];}catch{}; break;
        case "Yes" : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[1];}catch{}; break;
        case "No"  : try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value  = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Items[2];}catch{}; break;
    }

    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[8].ToString();}catch{}

    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value  = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[9].ToString();}catch{}
    try{dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = table.Rows[i].ItemArray[10].ToString();}catch{}
}
```

Comment: NOTE: I also had to do away with data binding. IMPORTANT!

Comment: NOTE 2: I also removed creating this table in Visual Studio, and on the RefreshDGV1 method, the columns are declared, followed by the calling of this ReadSQL method .